# Ruby no method error with HTTParty

Tags: ruby, http, post, rspec, httparty

I am trying to make a post request in Ruby and I am getting inconsistent behaviour. I am currently using ruby-2.0.0-p598 on OSX.

When using PRY and I type the following post command:

```
HTTParty.post(@base_uri + '/method/?argument1&api_key=' + @api_key)
```

I get a successful respond from the API. However when I run it through my specs or inside the class I get:

> undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

I know it has to do with the plus sign, but I find it weird that I am getting a different behaviour. Can you please suggest what is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like @base_uri and/or @api_key is null. Please double check if they are initialized with valid strings or not. Then try

```
 HTTParty.post("#{@base_uri}/method/?argument1&api_key=#{@api_key}")
```

In this case, ruby will automatically try to convert @base_uri and @api_key to string so no need to call to_s method explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Good day
Behavior correct - some variable = nil.
You have check variables, or (in this case it is better not to do) call to_s:

```
HTTParty.post(@base_uri.to_s + '/method/?argument1&api_key=' + @api_key.to_s)
```

Comment: Yeah it would have to be the first one, otherwise it would be a TypeError instead of a NoMethodErrror. I think in general it wouldnt be good to add #to_s, but as many people (or at least what I) would normally use interpolation here, it basically is the same thing.