# HTTParty undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

Using `HTTParty` gem to connect to a weather API I have the following method:

```
def weather_search
  @city_name = params[:city_name]
  url = URI.encode("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=#{@city_name}&APPID=#{API_TOKEN}")
  @search_result = HTTParty.get(url)
end
```

the gem is installed.

Using postman I can reach the API without problems with the following url

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=banfield&APPID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

However in my rails 4 app it the same url throws the error

`undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass` on the line where I declare

`@search_result = HTTParty.get(url)`

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985406/ruby-no-method-error-with-httparty) and [this other](https://forum.upcase.com/t/authentication-through-an-api-that-uses-devise/58) post on the subject but both are of no help.

Stack Trace:

```
Started POST "/search_city_weather" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-30 23:50:13 +0100
Processing by WeatherChecksController#weather_search as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "city_name"=>"banfield", "commit"=>"Search"}
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=banfield&APPID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms
NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/weather_checks_controller.rb:24:in `weather_search'
  Rendered /home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered /home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (22.6ms)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What does the stacktrace from that error say?

Comment: Hi @BenY see stack trace in main body of Q

Comment: Why doesn't your URI have `http://` in it?

Comment: because I'm a retard....@tadman pop it in an answer and will happily accept it. Thx.

Answer (score 6):

As written by @tadman you should provide a valid URI for httparty,
so:

- http://foo.com/resource, will work.
- foo.com/resource, won't.

By the way in versions newer than 0.14.0, 
Httparty will return this error, in those situations:
`URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):`

Much more clear than this

```
undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass
```